# How to disable keyboard tap sound on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

How do we disable the keyboard tap sound programatically? I am sure it's a setting in UItextfield.

Comment: This is a user preference that IMHO you should not interfere with unless you have a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I was able to find is how to subclass particular views to disable sound:

[Can I disable UIPickerView scroll sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441849/can-i-disable-uipickerview-scroll-sound)

I can't test this at work, but *if* it is possible, this may be related. `UIKeyboard` is a class that you can't actually subclass though, nor even declare. You can find an actual reference to it though via the following method:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6573-howto-customize-uikeyboard.html

Also, in the `UIKeyboardImpl` header file, I do see the `setSoundsEnabled` method:

http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs/_u_i_keyboard_impl_8h-source.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this value. It's a user preference and only controllable through the Settings App.