# iPad View Rotation Duration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

When changing the orientation of the iPad, my app rotates its view very fast. It is difficult to perceive the transition between both orientations. I would like to increase a little bit the duration of this transition.

Does anyone know how to increase the duration of this transition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from iPhone OS 3.2, UIApplication includes the `-windowRotationDuration` method, which returns the duration of rotation. It is 0.3 seconds in iPhone mode, and 0.4 seconds in iPad mode. You could override this method to change the rotation speed, e.g.

```
@implementation UIApplication (OverrideRotationSpeed)
-(NSTimeInterval)windowRotationDuration { return 5.0; }
@end
```

Now, `-windowRotationDuration` is a [private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000681/what-are-private-apis), which means you can't use this method, and there are no documented ways to do so, therefore the answer is:-

**No.**

Comment: But other apps that I have installed in my iPad behaves different. They have a smooth transition when rotating the device. I am using the default split view controller as it cames with no modifications, so either i am not understanding well what I have to do, or there must be a way to modify this behavior. :s

Comment: @federivo: Smooth transition ≠ Slower transition. It's probably your view is too complex. Try to reduce the hierarchy depth.

Comment: You are right. The problem is probably related to the composition of views I am using. 
I composed the detail view of the splitViewController this way: DetailView -> BackgroundView -> ClientView. The background view is used so I can reuse the clientView in portrait and landscape. When in portrait I set background view behind client view to give the impression of having margins and I take it away when changing to landscape. I guess I need to rethink this whole process or figure out another way to reuse client view for both orientations.
Thanks @KennyTM !