# changing allow popover arrow of a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to set the available popover arrow when presenting a UIActionSheet, as of now here's how I am displaying my UIActionSheet:

```
[self.optionsActionSheet_ showFromRect:frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

however the arrow is pointing to the right, I want it so that it points up. How do I do that? 
I know how to access the UIPopoverController is by this:

```
 ((UIPopoverController *) [[self.optionsActionSheet_ superview] superview])
```

but how do I change the arrow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *won't* access the `UIPopoverController`, since `UIPopoverController` isn't a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: You cannot do it without using either private APIs or private implementation details that may change in future versions of iOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActionSheet Change arrow position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763324/uiactionsheet-change-arrow-position)

Comment: hmm.. so in this case, how would I adjust the frame so that it shows an up arrow?