# Actionsheet with arrow using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to show Actionsheet with an arrow in my iPad app. I need this arrow to be displayed at a different position (may be based on the object being tapped)

[image]

Comment: Apple does not provide a method for you to change the arrow position of actionsheet. You have to write a custom actionsheet instead and implement this function by yourself. If you use a [UIActionSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiactionsheet?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)(Which is deprecated since iOS 8), you can try the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763324/uiactionsheet-change-arrow-position).

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not using Xamarin.Forms, but rather Xamarin.iOS, so please specify that

Comment: @IvanIčin Not sure why did you ask but to answer, I am using Xamarin.Forms. In my use case, I have one button on the top right side of the page and I wanted to provide multiple actions to the users on the click of the button.

I was searching if I can provide a dropdown menu kind of UI where the user can select an action. The above interface could solve my purpose so I asked. 

Now that I gave my use-case, do you happen to have any solution for me?

Comment: @user3496276 I've asked because if you are using Xamarin.Forms it is easier to discard the view and build it in Xamarin.iOS than to make this work in Xamarin.Forms... So it is expected that something like this is not tried, you can see also that one Microsoft employee provided you with answer for Xamarin.iOS...

Comment: @user3496276 considering the solution there is no ready made solution as Xamarin.Forms were not made for that. You can always make some Grids that cover part of the screen and make it look somewhat similar to what you want. But if you want the native control used above in that way you need to use Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it before using with Rg.Plugins.Popup. I created a frame and added a triangular image below the frame.
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup