# What is the best way to create multiple, separate flyout-style items in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, interface

Is there a way to create multiple different interface items similar to Xamarin Shell's flyout interface that can be activated from a single page (but not from other pages in my app), and which can contain multiple types of content?  I am looking for something similar to what is seen in this video, taken of Microsoft Teams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GIa0UcOZAk

I have been looking for documentation on this, but I don't even know what this would be called, besides calling it a "flyout menu", but this refers to the single menu that's made available by Shell.

Comment: Hi , it seems like a customed pop-up view from shared video . Do you mean that want to achieve the effect such as this shared ?

Comment: Yes, the video demonstrates exactly what I want to be able to do.

Comment: Okey, sorry for that there is no sample code to share with you , but you can have a look at this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945863/actionsheet-with-arrow-using-xamarin) .  The solution that is using https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup to custom a pop-up view to achieve that .

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this plugin and it does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Okey , that's great ! You can update that in answer when have time , then other people will know the solution :-)