# UIBarButtonItem frame?

Tags: uibarbuttonitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figure out UIBarButtonItem frame in window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994354/figure-out-uibarbuttonitem-frame-in-window)

I want to shrink a UIView (using scale animation) to a UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolbar. I can (sort of) calculate the button's frame using the toolbar's frame and the relative position of the button within the frame, but I'm wondering whether there's a more straightforward way to do this without using private APIs.