# ios - Get coordinates or CGPoint of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, cgpoint

I need to get the CGPoint of a UIBarButtonItem. I know I can get them of a normal UIButton by doing this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
  {
    CGPoint coordinates = sender.frame.origin;
  }
```

But this does not seem to work if I alter it for a UIBarButtonItem.
The reason I need the program to return these values to me, is because otherwise with the iPhone 5, the 4S and before screen I need to set up 3 possible positions when I include the landscape version, which I will do if there is no easier way to achieve this.

Comment: What happens in different screens (in landscape) if you don't do anything? Does it not adjust automatically?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem do not have a frame property - so this code won't do the job

Comment: Er, could you clearly explain why you need this?

Comment: I have a pop over that is activated when the button is pressed and I need to go where the UIBarButton is located, which can be in 3 places when you look at the coordinates. The example above avoids a lot of code, but I can't get it to work just as simple for the button I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994354/figure-out-uibarbuttonitem-frame-in-window).

As was pointed out, UIBarButtonItem does not extend UIView thus it has no frame property. The work around offered in the link is a private API and is typically not recommended.

```
UIView* barView = sender.view;
CGRect barFrame = [barView convertRect:barView.bounds toView:nil];
```

There is another solution offered in the link too.

Comment: Cool thanks for that - I have got it sussed, but it is just managed with if statements based on the type of device that uses the app.