# iPhone Datepicker plays 'tick' sound

Tags: iphone, audio, datepicker

Does any of you know what event I can tap into on the DatePicker when the wheel moves.

I want to play a sound (got sound code) as the wheel spin. Just like the timer set picker in Apple's clock app.

All that is there is a single event for ValueChanges which only fires once, at the end of a wheel spin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify - I would need to disable the existing click sound and add a new sound to the same event. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable UIPickerView scroll sound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441849/can-i-disable-uipickerview-scroll-sound)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible, as the sounds seem to be linked to the Keyboard Clicks in the phone settings. Maybe someone else has a solution, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented method for doing this:
[Disable UIPickerView sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441849/can-i-disable-uipickerview-scroll-sound/1441949#1441949)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SilentUIPickerView: UIPickerView
{ }

- (void) setSoundsEnabled: (BOOL) enabled;
@end
```

use this subclass and call `[view setSoundsEnabled: NO]`

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind this is when your controller is load the datepickr is scrolling so in view did load
write this code.

```
NSDate *d = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[objDatePicker setDate:d animated:NO];
```