# Is it possible to load UIImagePickerController.Camera with attribute of silent shutter sound

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I've just learned to implement setting `CameraModeFlash.Off` when presenting `UIImagePickerController.Camera`.

Is there any way to make the default shutter sound silent??

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVFoundation, how to turn off the shutter sound when captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401232/avfoundation-how-to-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-when-capturestillimageasynchrono)

Comment: My question pertains to UIImagPickerController...without having to dive into AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove the shutter sound, unless your user has put the phone on silent mode. You can [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401232/avfoundation-how-to-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-when-capturestillimageasynchrono) your way through by playing an inverted audio when the shutter captures (with `AVFoundation`).

You might not want to turn off shutter sounds with this hacky method either, because in countries like Japan, shutter sounds MUST be on regardless of if silent mode on or not.

Comment: is it possible to get the property of... if device is on 'silent mode or not'?

Comment: @Dustin [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki) and [this](http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/)