# Screen capture during video preview fails

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to capture the screen while doing a video preview with AVFoundation (AVCaptureDeviceInput and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput)

Initiate preview:

```
func startCamera(){
    var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size;
    self.previewView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height));
    self.previewView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(previewView);

    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices();
    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice;
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil
    var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!, error: &err);

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)");
    }
    if session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
        session.addInput(deviceInput);
    }

    videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    if let videoDataOutput = videoDataOutput {
        var rgbOutputSettings = [NSNumber(integer: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA):kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true;
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
        if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
            session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
        }
        videoDataOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).enabled = true

        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight

            var rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer;
            rootLayer.masksToBounds=true;
            previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds;
            rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer);
            session.startRunning();

            delay(8, closure: { () -> () in
                self.processImage()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Code to capture the screen:

```
func processImage() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)
    previewLayer!.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    // tried previewView!.layer.render... to no avail
    let previewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    savePDFImage(previewImage, name: "front.pdf")
}
```

The image returned is just all white. How do I grab a screenshot of what's on the screen while doing a video preview?

Comment: Why don't you use  AVCaptureStillImageOutput() ?

Comment: I need to do some pre-processing to see if I want to grab the full-resolution image or not. This pre-processing is meant to be on the low-resolution screen preview.

Comment: Do you want a screen shot or a regular picture?

Comment: You can resize the image. Do you know how to take a still picture and resize it ? I can show you how to generate a low res picture from the camera

Comment: No, I don't want to have a clicking sound every half second for each capture as I process the image to see if I *want* to do a capture. Once the app has determined that certain conditions are met, I do the full-res capture and allow the click.

Comment: So I can't help I don't know how to disable the camera sound and when I try to do a snapshot it also gives me a plain white image

Comment: Okay, it seems I need to work with the delegate method: captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) { }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't capture the screen. Instead, capture a frame from the buffer and use that.

Implement the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.

On the VideoDataOuput, set the setSampleBufferDelegate

Implement the captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) method.

When you store the image to the device, play the shutter sound yourself.

In the end, your code looks more like this:

```
var videoDataOutput:AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?;
var videoDataOutputQueue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
var stillImageOutput:AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
let session = AVCaptureSession()

func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil
    var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!, error: &err);

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)");
    }
    if session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
        session.addInput(deviceInput);
    }

    stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    if let videoDataOutput = videoDataOutput, stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput {
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true;
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
        if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput){
            session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        }

        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

        videoDataOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).enabled = true

        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight

            var rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer;
            rootLayer.masksToBounds=true;
            previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds;
            rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer);
            session.startRunning();
        }
    }
}

// this gets called periodically with an image
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if let image = CheckResponse.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        if keepImage(image) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
            session.stopRunning()
        }
    }
}

// This is in the Objective-C CheckResponse class to get an image from the buffer:
+ (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer {
    CVPixelBufferRef pb = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage *ciimg = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pb];

    // show result
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef ref = [context createCGImage:ciimg fromRect:ciimg.extent];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientationUp)];

    CFRelease(ref);

    return image;
}
```