# iPhone UIPickerView not playing selection sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview, uipicker

I have a UIPickerView in my app in which the 'tick' sound when moving from one index to the next is not played. I swear it used to play the sound, but recently it has not played.

I am using custom labels for each item in the picker, and I tried commenting that out and the sound still does not play.

I have searched around and saw there is a method [pickerView setSoundsEnabled:YES], but it is a private API, so I cannot use that.

Most threads I have found are people trying to stop the sound from playing, shouldn't it be playing the sound by default?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with using the FMOD library. I filed a bug report, it was when using the PLAY_AND_RECORD filter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this sound is set/unset via the system-level preferences panel, **Settings->Sounds->Keyboard Clicks->On**, and cannot be set at the API level (at least, not officially).

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious... Is your ringer mute switch on?

Comment: I'm testing on an iPad, nothing is on mute or off. The issue happens on any other device as well, iPhone 3, 4, 4S..

Comment: Last guess: In a [thread about trying to eliminate the sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441849/can-i-disable-uipickerview-scroll-sound), cbranch mentions a clever trick he used to kill the unwanted audio. Any chance you've happened to inadvertently do the same by removing/adding the view from its superview?

Comment: I did see that and I am not removing/ adding it to the superview at all, the only thing I am doing a lot is reloading the data when the user switches tabs. I also noticed that the 'tap' does not even play when typing in the keyboard, I am starting to think it has to do with me using the FMOD audio library. I feel it may be screwing with the system sounds. Thanks for your suggestions!