# Can the clicking sound of UIDatePicker be disabled?

Tags: uidatepicker

I'm not sure if I am overlooking an obvious setting, but is there a way to disable the clicking of a UIDatePicker when the value of the date picker is changed (by the user of programmatically)?

During my search, I have come across an undocumented method, but that is not what I am planning to adopt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, it seems that the clicks generated by UIPickerView can only be disabled by the user in the global settings of the device. This also disables the keyboard clicks as a result. A similar questions was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441849/can-i-disable-uipickerview-scroll-sound).