# Swift - Is it possible to disable the click sound when scrolling a UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, audio, uipickerview

I would like to disable the sound when a user scrolls trough the items in a UIPickerview. My app is created with the Swift 3 language.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614689/can-the-clicking-sound-of-uidatepicker-be-disabled

Comment: Thx Joe. I hope there will be an answer soon