# MPMusicPlayerController and using Private API to get current queue

Tags: ios, swift

There is an answer on this question: [iOS - get programatically queue of items currently playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092589/ios-get-programatically-queue-of-items-currently-playing) that describes how to do this, however I am trying that method and it does not work. Here is my code:

```
  let numberOfItems = player.value(forKey: "numberOfItems") as! Int
  for i in 0..<numberOfItems {

    if let mediaItem = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.perform(Selector("nowPlayingItemAtIndex:"), with: i)?.takeUnretainedValue() as? MPMediaItem {
            let songObject = mediaItem.value(forKey: "propertyValues") as! NSObject
            print(songObject.value(forKey: "title"))
            print(mediaItem.title)
            print(mediaItem.value(forKey: "title"))
            print(mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))
        }
    }
```

All 4 print statements are nil. It is worth noting that it can indeed cast the item as an MPMediaItem, and the songObject variable actually prints as a MPModelSong. The runtime headers indicate there is a property on MPModelSong objects "title" (found here: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MPModelSong.h)

No matter what, everything prints nil. Any idea what direction I should head from here?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet so that i can try it out

Comment: that is my entire code. regardless, nowPlayingItemAtIndex: does not work anymore in iOS 12.2, it does not return any value at all.